# High Score in Train Test Split but Low Score in CV in Python Scikit-Learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, virtual-machine, random-forest, cross-validation

I am new in Data Science and have struggled in the problem for the Kaggle's problem. When I use random forest regression for predicting the rating, it is found high Score using Train Test Split but Low Score while using CV Score.

- with train test split_randomforest 0.8746277302652172
- with no train test split_randomforest 0.8750717943467078
- with CV randomforest 10.713885026374156 %

https://www.kaggle.com/data13/machine-learning-model-to-predict-app-rating-94

```py
import time
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
import statsmodels.api as sm
import sklearn.model_selection as ms
from sklearn import neighbors
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.neighbors import KDTree
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, ShuffleSplit
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV


from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from xgboost import XGBRegressor 
from lightgbm import LGBMClassifier


database = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Anson\Downloads\49864_274957_bundle_archive\googleplaystore.csv")# store wine type as an attribute



## Size - Strip the M and k value 
database['Size'] = database['Size'].apply(lambda x : x.strip('M'))
database['Size'] = database['Size'].apply(lambda x : x.strip('k'))
##

## Rating - Fill the Blank Value with median
database['Rating'].fillna(database['Rating'].median(),inplace=True)
database['Rating'].replace(19,database['Rating'].median(),inplace=True) 

###


## Reviews -  replace the blank cell
database['Reviews'].replace('3.0M',3000000,inplace=True) 
database['Reviews'].replace('0',float("NaN"),inplace=True) 
database.dropna(subset=['Reviews'],inplace=True)
##


## Strip the + value
database['Installs'] = database['Installs'].apply(lambda x : x.strip('+'))
database['Installs'] = database['Installs'].apply(lambda x : x.replace(',',''))
database['Price'] = database['Price'].apply(lambda x : x.strip('$'))
###

## Drop Blank 
database['Content Rating'].fillna("NaN",inplace=True)
database.dropna(subset=['Content Rating'],inplace=True)
##

## Drop Wrong Number 
database['Last Updated'].replace('1.0.19',float("NaN"),inplace=True) 
database.dropna(subset=['Last Updated'],inplace=True)
database['Last Updated'] = database['Last Updated'].apply(lambda x : time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%B %d, %Y').timetuple()))
##




le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
database['App'] = le.fit_transform(database['App'])
database['Category'] = le.fit_transform(database['Category'])
database['Content Rating'] = le.fit_transform(database['Content Rating'])
database['Type'] = le.fit_transform(database['Type'])
database['Genres'] = le.fit_transform(database['Genres'])




###############################
##feature engineering

features = ['App', 'Reviews', 'Type', 'Price', 'Content Rating', 'Genres', 'Last Updated']

X=database[features]
y=database['Rating']

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=None)


rfc= RandomForestRegressor()


rfc.fit(X_train,y_train)
rfc.fit(X,y)

rfc_score=rfc.score(X_test,y_test)
rfc_score1=rfc.score(X,y)
score_CV_randomforest = cross_val_score(rfc,X,y,cv=KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True),scoring='r2')

score_CV_randomforest = score_CV_randomforest.mean()*100


print("with train test split_randomforest", rfc_score)
print("with no train test split_randomforest", rfc_score1)
print("with CV randomforest", score_CV_randomforest, "%")
```

Comment: It is hard to understand your very long title:) Maybe "Score" should be "score" and maybe there are too many "Score"s in there.

Answer (score 1):

**Train/Test Split:**
You are using 80:20 ratio fro training and testing.

**Cross-validation**
when the data set is randomly split up into ‘k’ groups. One of the groups is used as the test set and the rest are used as the training set. The model is trained on the training set and scored on the test set. Then the process is repeated until each unique group as been used as the test set.
You are using 5-fold cross validation, the data set would be split into 5 groups, and the model would be trained and tested 5 separate times so each group would get a chance to be the test set.

So the **reason for different result** is, that model is trained on different random samples.